# Why does "toys" (plural) translate as Spielzeug (toy, singular) when used with liegen?

Tags: english-to-german

These two English sentences use a plural nominative noun with the intransitive verb 'to lie'

- There are broken toys in many children's rooms.
- Broken toys lie on the floor.

But when translated to German (using DEEPL or Google Translate), the plural **broken toys**  becomes the singular **kaputtes Spielzeug**:

- In vielen Kinderzimmern gibt es kaputtes Spielzeug.
- Zerbrochenes Spielzeug liegt auf dem Boden.

How does one best explain this puzzling, unexpected grammatical change from the plural to the singular?

Comment: Is there a change? One is english, the other is German. Two different languages.

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Spielzeug

Comment: This is related to a [question I asked a year ago](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/65309/43989).

Comment: @Bernhard Döbler: Usually uncountable nouns are finely divisible; for example you have to work hard to pick a grain of sand from a pile of sand, and sand/*Sand* is uncountable in both languages. But *Spielzeug* seems to be an exception in German; you can easily pick out an individual toy from a pile of *Spielzeug*. There are similar exceptions in English, for example "equipment", but there is natural confusion when you run into an exception which seems to have no reason behind it.

Comment: @RDBury: "But Spielzeug seems to be an exception in German; you can easily pick out an individual toy from a pile of Spielzeug." - I'm not so sure about this. I have a somewhat hard time saying that a single Lego brick, for example, is "a toy". For what it's worth, the play value of a single Lego brick is rather limited. Once you have two or more of them, this changes, but then it is arguably a "mass" that you rather shovel around in higher quantities than as individual objects. Likewise, is a toy car and a toy trailer one toy or two toys? This way of being somewhat unclear as to what ...

Comment: ... constitutes an "atomic unit" makes it easy to think of toys as an uncountable mass IMHO.

Comment: "play stuff" ...

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: The boundary between countable and uncountable is fuzzy, and my "tweezers" criterion is only meant to approximate. When it comes to fuzzy boundaries different languages usually disagree when it comes to the details. It takes language learners a while to adjust. An example going the other way is the hair on one's head; countable (plural) in German but uncountable in English.

Comment: @RDBury: Oh, in German, "das Haar" can also mean the entirety of hair on someone's head. So, in German, "Haar" is a noun that can be used as countable and uncountable, just like "Spielzeug". (Also, note that in my comment, I didn't mean to imply that English was somehow "wrong". I rather wanted to point out that, while your explanation about picking an individual toy is usually correct, one could also find an explanation why "toys" would be denoted with a mass noun. As both explanations end up somewhat reasonable, it's easy to see how different languages happen to find different solutions.)

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: You're right. The plural is more noticeable for me because "My hairs are grey" sounds wrong in English. But going over my notes I see examples where the singular is used. *Dein Haar glänzt wie ein Sternenfeld* from the song "Marleen".

Answer (score 9):

"Spielzeug" is used here as an uncountable noun, like many nouns on "-zeug" (Werkzeug, Strickzeug, ...), and much like "rice" or "information" in English. In German, uncountable nouns go with a verb in singular.

The plural "Spielzeuge" does exist, too, and it is also used. I'd say it's mostly a question of taste whether to use the one or the other here.

You get the opposite effect with "information" which is a countable noun in German.

> English: The exec shared *information* about the new product with the press.
> German: Der Manager gab der Presse *Informationen* über das neue Produkt.

Comment: One nitpick, "fish" isn't uncountable in English unless you're talking about food ingredients. It's just that most the time the plural is the same as the singular; while "fishes" does exist, it's not used very often. For example, "There are 5 fish in this aquarium." Nouns whose plural is the same as the singular are much more rare in English than in German; I can't think of another exception at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @RDBury, I changed it to  a differert example.

Comment: @HalvarF Thanks for the helpful clarification!